# Difference between scala.concurrent.onComplete and akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.onComplete

Tags: scala, akka-http

In scala concurrent package, there is `onComplete` method which returns nothing while in `akka-http` directives, it returns the Directive1.

Is that the only difference? I sometimes got confused on those two methods.

Answer (score 1):

These methods are different in what they aim to accomplish, but they are related in that the akka http `onComplete` is meant to work with the completion of a `Future` in order to complete the routing of a request.

The concurrent `onComplete` is a method on a `Future` that is meant to perform some sort of side effecting when the `Future` has completed.  There are a lot of other methods on a `Future` like `map`, `flatMap` and `filter` that will produce another `Future` as you go through a series of transforms, but `onComplete` returns nothing, and is sort of a "dead end" in the processing of that `Future`.

An example of using `onComplete` while also showing how something like `map` can be used to change the `Future` is as follows:

```
val fut1 = Future{"1"} // A Future[String]
val fut2 = fut1.map(_.toInt) // Now a Future[Int]
fut2.onComplete{
  case util.Success(i) => println(s"success: $i")
  case util.Failure(ex) => ex.printStackTrace()
}

val badFut1 = Future{"A"}
val badFut2 = badFut.map(_.toInt) //Will be failed
badFut2.onComplete{
  case util.Success(i) => println(s"success: $i")
  case util.Failure(ex) => ex.printStackTrace()
}
```

In the first case, we will hit the success case as "1" can be mapped into an Int.  In the second example, we will hit the error case as "A" cannot be mapped to an Int.  Either way, you can see that something like `map` can be used to create a new transformed future while `onComplete` can be used to do something based on the final result of that `Future`.

In Akka Http, you sometimes need to create `Route` definitions that need to do something asynchronously.  In that case, you need to complete the route when that asynchronous task completed.  A `Route` itself needs to be fully defined in order to compile, so you can't leverage the existing `onComplete` on a `Future` because that returns nothing and that would render the definition of that `Route` as incomplete.  Therefore, the guys at Akka defined an `onComplete` directive that will snap into a routing tree and work with a `Future`, returning a `Directive` that will fully define the tree for that `Route` as oppose to leaving it open ended as the `Future.onComplete` would.  An example:

```
val myRoute = 
  get{
    val fut = myActor ? "foo"
    onComplete(foo){
      case util.Success(_) => complete(StatusCodes.OK)
      case util.Failure(ex) => complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError)
    }
  }
```

So here, I'm making a request to an `Actor` using `ask (?)` and I get a `Future` back.  I still need to produce something that completes the `Route` I am defining.  If I did something like this:

```
val myRoute = 
  get{
    val fut = myActor ? "foo"
    fut.onComplete{
      case util.Success(_) => complete(StatusCodes.OK)
      case util.Failure(ex) => complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError)
    }
  }
```

It worn't work because the `onComplete` here is the one from the `Future` and not the directive, and that returns `Unit` and my `Route` won't be full defined and won't compile.

So the `onComplete` directive is there to allow you to define a `Route` based on the completion of a `Future` which you can't do properly with the pre-existing `onComplete` from `Future` itself.